# SQL Server increment the row number for each new unique value

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get results like the following:

```
1 foo 1-Jan
2 bar 2-Feb
3 baz 3-Mar
3 baz 4-Apr
3 baz 5-May
4 quz 6-Jun
4 quz 7-Jul
```

with this T-SQL:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DateTime]) AS [SetNum], *
FROM [ComplicatedQuery]
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
1 foo 1-Jan
1 bar 2-Feb
1 baz 3-Mar
2 baz 4-Apr
3 baz 5-May
1 quz 6-Jun
2 quz 7-Jul
```

How can I change it to increment the row/set number for each new unique value of `[ID]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql) instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` thus:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [Column_with_foo_bar_baz_coco_jambo_etc]) AS Rnk
```

Tip: look at example `A. Ranking rows within a partition` from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql):
[image]

Comment: The three `baz` rows have different `DateTime` values but need to all be assigned `3`. `DENSE_RANK` alone isn't going to solve this.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because a) it works (if as shown in your example I don't use `PARTITION BY`) and b) it only needs one `SELECT` (the original one)

Answer (score 0):

We need to use two windowed aggregates to achieve your desired results - the first ensures that all rows for the same `ID` get assigned a single value to then use in the ordering criteria:

```
declare @t table (Desired int,ID varchar(9),Dt datetime)
insert into @t(Desired,ID,Dt) values
(1,'foo','20170101'),
(2,'bar','20170202'),
(3,'baz','20170303'),
(3,'baz','20170404'),
(3,'baz','20170505'),
(4,'quz','20170606'),
(4,'quz','20170707')

;With MinDt as (
select *,MIN(Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as MinDt
from @t
)
select *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MinDt,ID) as rk
from MinDt
```

Results:

```
Desired     ID        Dt                      MinDt                   rk
----------- --------- ----------------------- ----------------------- --------------------
1           foo       2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 1
2           bar       2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 2
3           baz       2017-03-03 00:00:00.000 2017-03-03 00:00:00.000 3
3           baz       2017-04-04 00:00:00.000 2017-03-03 00:00:00.000 3
3           baz       2017-05-05 00:00:00.000 2017-03-03 00:00:00.000 3
4           quz       2017-06-06 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06 00:00:00.000 4
4           quz       2017-07-07 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06 00:00:00.000 4
```

The inclusion of `ID` in the `DENSE_RANK` is to act as a tie-breaker in case multiple `ID` values have the same minimal `Dt` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [SetNum], ID into #temp
FROM [ComplicatedQuery]


SELECT t.SetNum AS [SetNum], cq.* 
FROM [ComplicatedQuery] cq join #temp t on cq.ID=t.ID order by t.SetNum
```

Comment: You do know you can edit answers, right? You can even edit them whilst they're deleted and then undelete them. There's no reason why you should have two deleted answers to this question in addition to this current one.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.